# What are the current approaches to topic modelling (i.e. better than LSA, LDA, LSI)?

Tags: machine-learning, topic-models, latent-semantic-analysis, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I am looking into methods for topic modeling with the purpose of keyword generation. Given a corpus consisting of multiple documents, I would like to get a list of semantically relevant and significant keywords.

What are the current approaches for this task of keyword extraction? So far I have found the following. Anything else?

Statistical models:

1. Hierarchical latent tree analysis - HLTA (Liu et al., 2014)
   Paper: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-662-44851-9_17.pdf
2. Non-negative matrix factorization - NMF in Arora, Ge, Halpern, Mimno, Moitra, Sontag, Wu, & Zhu (2013);
   Paper: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/arora13.html
   Also Arora et al., 2021: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1956
3. Probabilistic Latent Semantic Analysis - pLSA (Hofmann 1999)
   Paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6705
   Implementation e.g.: https://github.com/hitalex/PLSA

Deep learning models:

1. Replicated Softmax Model (RSM), combined with RBMs (Restricted Boltzmann Machines), Pre-Training and Auto-Encoders.
   Paper: "Discovering Binary Codes for Documents by Learning Deep Generative Models" (Hinton and Salakhutdinov, 2010) [http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~rsalakhu/papers/topics.pdf](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/%7Ersalakhu/papers/topics.pdf)
   Implementation: https://github.com/krenova/DeepLearningTopicModels
2. lda2vec (Moody 2016);
   Blog post;: https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/05/27/lda2vec/#topic=38&lambda=1&term=
   Code: https://github.com/cemoody/lda2vec (out of date and doesn't work)
3. Deep LDA (Bhat et al., 2020);
   Paper: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Tanveer_Tarray2/publication/334132970_Deep_LDA_A_new_way_to_topic_model/links/5d1cc1c092851cf440620070/Deep-LDA-A-new-way-to-topic-model.pdf
4. LSTM-Topic matrix factorization - LTMF (Jin et al., 2018).
   Paper: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N18-1145.pdf
5. Stochastic block model - SBM (Gerlach et al., 2018);
   Paper: https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/4/7/eaaq1360?rss=1&intcmp=trendmd-adv
6. Topic Modeling with BERT (Grootendorst); based on Top2Vec (Angelov 2020, https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.09470)
   Blog post: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/11/topic-modeling-bert.html
   Code: https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic

Thanks a lot.
Cheers,
Martin